# how can i get the element head or h1

Tags: c#, html, element

I want to get the value of the head which is inside the tag `<div>`. but still I'm not able to get it.

```
var source = inputXDoc.Descendants(GetNamespace(ref namespace2, "").GetName("body"));
if (source.Descendants(GetNamespace(ref namespace2, "").GetName("div")).Any())
{
    var introduced5 = inputXDoc.Descendants(GetNamespace(ref namespace2, "").GetName("body"));
    if (introduced5.Descendants(GetNamespace(ref namespace2, "").GetName("div")).First().Attributes("id").Any())
    {
        var introduced6 = inputXDoc.Descendants(GetNamespace(ref namespace2, "").GetName("body"));
        //_chapterName = introduced6.Descendants(GetNamespace(ref namespace2, "").GetName("div")).First().Attributes("id").First().Value;
        _chapterName = introduced6.Descendants(GetNamespace(ref namespace2, "").GetName("div")).First().Element("h")?.Value;
    }
}
```

Below is the html and what I want to get the value is **/The fox/**

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
<html xml:lang="" xmlns="">
    <head>
        <title>De title</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Digital.css"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>
            <a id="p7"/>
            <a id="ch1" href="005_inhoud.html#ch1">/The fox/</a>
        </h1>
        <p class="indent">the quick brown fox jump over the lazy dog</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use XPath extension to extract the element:

```
using System.Xml.XPath;

string title = inputXDoc.XPathSelectElement("//a[@id='ch1']").Value;
```

This XPath means literally:

> any `a` element having an attribute `id` equal to `ch1`

Here is [the working demo](http://rextester.com/IMX46953).

Comment: Im getting a system.nullreference exception.. object reference not set to an instance of an object. Is it possible to get the value of first element "h" after body?

Comment: @ErwinAlcantara No, it shouldn't. It's working for me :) Show the code which produces this error.

Comment: I try to modify the code and try to use xpathselectelement because I encounter this **<h3 class="sgc-5">Air<sup class="fn-num"><a id="r_fn1" href="#fn1">1</a></sup></h3>** Generally I want to change my logic to get the first **h** element (h1, h2, h3) Value. is it possible? @Yeldar